# Как улучшить конструкцию if else по сбору характеристик?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Как привести к более красивому виду код? Я реализовал через if else, но выглядит достаточно убого:

```
  const makeRecomendations = (wordsPerMinute, newAverage) => {
    if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length < 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && newAverage <=5 && output.length < 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите громче'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && newAverage >=8 && output.length < 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите тише'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=8) && output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите тише\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage <=5) && output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите громче\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute  >= 180 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length < 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && newAverage <=5 && output.length < 1) return 'Говорите громче'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && newAverage >=8 && output.length < 1) return 'Говорите тише'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) && output.length >= 1) return 'Контролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if ((wordsPerMinute >= 119 && wordsPerMinute <= 180)  && newAverage <=5 &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Говорите громче\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute >=180  && newAverage <=5 &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада\nГоворите громче\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute >=180  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) &&  output.length < 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада'
    else if (wordsPerMinute >=180  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Не торопитесь во время доклада\nКонтролируйте употребление слов паразитов'
    else if (wordsPerMinute <= 119  && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <= 8) &&  output.length >= 1) return 'Увеличьте скорость речи'
    else return "Вы потрясающий спикер!"

  }
```

Comment: Как минимум, можно убрать все `else`. У вас после каждого условия есть `return`, значит в последующие if-ы вы и так не попадете, если какое-либо из условий сработает.

Comment: а последняя строчка?)

Comment: Думаю что гораздо продуктивнее будет вычислять три характеристики раздельно, а потом их собрать в одно сообщение...

Comment: @Proger228 и последний return выполнится тоже только в том случае, если не сработает ни одно из условий.

Comment: @Proger228 но это программа минимум. Лучше в принципе переписать логику кода. ksa вам правильную идею подсказал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант с разделением проверок...

```js
const output = ['значит', 'короче']
const makeRecomendations = (wordsPerMinute, newAverage) => {
  const a = []
  if (wordsPerMinute <= 119) a.push('Увеличьте скорость речи')
  if (wordsPerMinute >= 180) a.push('Не торопитесь во время доклада')
  if (newAverage <= 5) a.push('Говорите громче')
  if (newAverage >= 8) a.push('Говорите тише')
  if (output.length) a.push('Контролируйте употребление слов паразитов')
  if (a.length) return a.join('\n')
  return 'Вы потрясающий спикер!'
}

const mess = makeRecomendations(100, 4)
console.log(mess)
```

Answer (score 4):

В качестве разнообразия предложу еще вариант: можно создать массив `recomendations`, который будет содержать условие для рекомендации и сообщение. И в функции пройтись по этому массиву, поочередно проверяя условия.

```js
const recomendations = [
  {
    condition: (wordsPerMinute, newAverage, output) => (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && (newAverage >=5 && newAverage <=8) && output.length < 1),
    message: 'Увеличьте скорость речи',
  },
  {
    condition: (wordsPerMinute, newAverage, output) => (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && newAverage <=5 && output.length < 1),
    message: 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите громче',
  },
  {
    condition: (wordsPerMinute, newAverage, output) => (wordsPerMinute  <= 119 && newAverage >=8 && output.length < 1),
    message: 'Увеличьте скорость речи\nГоворите тише',
  },
  // и т.д.
];

const noRecomendations = 'Вы потрясающий спикер!';

function makeRecomendations_v2(wordsPerMinute, newAverage) {
  for (let recomendation of recomendations) {
    if (recomendation.condition(wordsPerMinute, newAverage, output)) {
      return recomendation.message;
    }
  }

  return noRecomendations;
}

const recomendation = makeRecomendations_v2(119, 4);
```